# Do I need to seal the rotating seams of a duct elbow?

Tags: kitchens, ducts

Kitchen range hood installation questions:

- Do I need to seal the points indicated by the arrows?

[image]

- Any opinions on mastic over foil tape?  I have some 3M 3340 laying around.
- Can mastic be used inside the ducts or will that impede air flow?

Comment: Mods: Should I create separate questions?

Comment: I have never messed with vent 90’s they will be sealed up soon enough. I would never put something on the inside.

Answer (score 1):

Common (green) practice is duct sealant plus tape (foil tape is fine).    All bends and joins get this.   Should be one of the last things you do before drywall though.  You don't want to do this, have an open wall for 2 months and be bumping the duct work while doing other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to seal those but when I did mine, I did seal it simply to prevent it from turn and shift angle while I was working on it. I would use foil tape on the inside, foil tape is very thin. Also, wipe the elbow with some alcohol or some sort of degreaser as they most likely little oily.